# Box Plot Trellis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas, boxplot

Consider I have some data.
Lets say it is weather data, of rainfall and temperature for each month.
For this example, I will randomly generate is like so:

```
def rand_weather(n):
    month = n%12+1
    temp_ind = np.random.randint(0,4)
    temp = ["freezing", "cold", "moderate", "hot", "extreme"][temp_ind]
    rain = np.random.normal(50 - 4*temp_ind, 25) + np.random.randint(0,20)
    return month,rain, temp

data = [rand_weather(n) for n in range(3000)]
rain_record = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["month", "rainfall", "temp"])
```

So the data looks something like:

```
    month   rainfall      temp
0       1  78.364133      cold
1       2  54.290201  freezing
2       3  81.341265      cold
3       4  98.980334       hot
...     ...    ...     ...
12      1  66.378066  moderate
13      2  44.264323  moderate
...     ...    ...     ...
```

**I want to draw a [Trellis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_multiple) chart of [Box plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot).**

---

I can draw a Trellis Chart of the means like so:

```
avgs = rain_record.groupby(['temp','month']).mean()
avgs.reset_index(inplace=True) #Make the 'temp' and 'month' columns again

import pandas.tools.rplot as rplot
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6), dpi=20)
plt.title=pattern

plot = rplot.RPlot(avgs, y='rainfall', x='month')
plot.add(rplot.TrellisGrid(['temp', '.']))
plot.add(rplot.GeomScatter())
#plot.add(rplot.GeomPoint(size=80.0, alpha=0.5))
t=plot.render(plt.gcf())
```

[image: trellis_of means]

---

And I can draw a box plot of each `'temp'` like so (for 'cold'):

```
rain_record[rain_record.temp=='cold'].boxplot(by='month')
```

[image: box_plot]

I could loop though each temp to generate as series of them.
But the axis would not intrinsically line up, like they would in a Trellis.
I guess the option exists to manaully setup matplotlibs axis,
but I'm not sure of a nice way to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/), specifically the `factorplot` function:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

sns.factorplot("month", "rainfall", row="temp", data=rain_record,
               size=2, aspect=5, kind="box", palette="PuBuGn_d")
sns.despine(left=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Truely the extended scientific python ecosystem is vast, and interconnected.

Comment: Is there a way to make the X position of the plot propertional to the value? Say if i was only took readings on month 3, 6, and 12, I would want the gap between 6 and 16 to be bigger than the gap between 3 and 6.

Comment: No, `factorplot` always assumes that the values on the x axis are categorical (even when they might seem quantitative).